# Long execution times for INSERT INTO SELECT Statement with remote server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following problem with MS SQL Server Express edition. When doing the following SQL Query 5000 times and for each time incrementing the SEQ number (1-5000) the execution time is about 38 seconds:

```
INSERT INTO [EXPLORER\SQLEXPRESS2014].CentralServer.dbo.f_ORDRE 
SELECT * FROM [EXPLORER\SQLEXPRESS2014].Local.dbo.ORDER WHERE SEQ = 1;
```

All the activities are done on the local machine. And the total time is as expected. The record size of ORDRE is about 560 bytes. Now, if I do the INSERT to a remote server as below I get an execution time of close to 9 minutes for 5000 records. The FRACTALSERVER has a 1 Gbit Ethernet Connection. The network packet size was changed from 4096 to 8192 bytes without any change in execution time:

```
INSERT INTO [FRACTALSERVER\FRACTASQLEXPRESS].CentralServer.dbo.f_ORDRE 
SELECT * FROM [EXPLORER\SQLEXPRESS2014].Local.dbo.ORDER WHERE SEQ = 1;
```

Why is the execution time in the last case so long (14 times longer!). I can’t understand that. Can anybody give a hint of what I’m doing wrong or give an indication where the problem might be?

Comment: Look at execution plan. Maybe an index for SEQ column is missing on remote server?

Comment: Can you send those 5000 queries as a 1 batch instead of 5000 batches with 1 query - does it make any difference?